how to apply wav2lip model on talknet ASD model
how to apply wav2lip model on talknet ASD model
In ASD model we get green box for active speaker and red boxes for non active speaker. I tried to get scores of asd model and green box of active speaker, I tried to implement wav2lip model for only that green boundary box person, but not successful. Please suggest how can I approach to get the solution
